# how to use ng-if condition with strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, factory

i have a response coming form webservice as "No Attachments found"  and "attachment found". i want to show 2 different images on a page one on no attachment found case and another on attachment found case .

here is my html :

```
  <div  style="float:left">
        <img src="img/icon_doc_active.png " style="width:20px" ng-if="hasdocument(response == "attachment found")" ng-click="findDoc() "></img>

       <img src="img/icon_doc_inactive.png " style="width:20px" ng-if="!hasdocument(response=="no attachment found")"></img>
   </div>
```

here is my controller :

```
  $scope.responseofdoc = [];

    $scope.findDoc = function() {
                    $scope.urlObj = [];
                    $scope.docCheck = false;
                    $scope.docListCheck = false;
                    $scope.cLoader = true;
                    $scope.docMsg = "No Attachment found";
                    $scope.docModalOpen = true;
                    attachmentService.fetchAttachmentId(temp).then(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response == "No Attachments found") {
                                console.log("my response");
                                $scope.responseofdoc.push(response == "No Attachments found");
                                console.log( $scope.responseofdoc);
                                $scope.docMsg = response;
                                $scope.docCheck = true;
                                $scope.cLoader = false;
                                // $scope.docListCheck = false;
                            } else {
                                console.log("found attachment");
                                console.log("my response");
                                $scope.docListCheck = true;
                                var data = JSON.parse(response);
                                //  $scope.urlObj = [];
                                getDocBase64(data);
                            }
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            $scope.docMsg = "Error while fetching attachment";
                            $scope.docCheck = true;
                            $scope.cLoader = false;
                        });

                }
```

how will i check the string response coming inside  $scope.responseofdoc = []; array with the ng-if condition inside my html and show the required image of document ?

Comment: Try this -> ng-if="hasdocument(response == 'attachment found')"

Comment: should i make another function to check the value of the response bcz i m using it into findDoc function . and pushed he values in $scope.responseofdoc array ?

Answer (score 0):

In your html try :

```
<div  style="float:left">
  <img src="img/icon_doc_active.png " style="width:20px" ng-if="hasdocument(response == 'attachment found')" ng-click="findDoc() "></img>

  <img src="img/icon_doc_inactive.png " style="width:20px" ng-if="!hasdocument(response == 'no attachment found')"></img>
</div>
```

when you use double quote it conflicts with the double quote you have used for attribute. So when you use double quote compare with single quote and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your closing the ng-if attribute on the element in your HTML. You should use single quotes:

```
ng-if="hasdocument(response == 'attachment found')"
```

Change this for both elements and it should work.